# How to *correctly* ask for permissions?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm developing an Android app that requires 3 permissions on startup. I have to wait until the user to responds at the dialogs, if not, the app crashes as the permissions are mandatory.

What is the correct way to ask for those permissions? I wrote the below code, but the app freezes when responding the first permission (either rejecting or accepting).

Here is what I made:

```
    String[] perms = {"Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE", "Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION","Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE"};

    int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    int result3 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

    if ((result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (result3 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        onPermissionGranted();
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(perms, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, perms, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                onPermissionGranted();
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.permission_required, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.


            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1000)` - Don't do this. There's no need to block any threads, and this is blocking the UI thread, which will mean your UI will freeze.

Comment: Still freezes after first permission (I'm testing on android 8.0)

Comment: Could you update your question? You've removed the while loops as well I take it? Again, there's no need for this, permission requests are asynchronous

Comment: If do not loop, the app continues running and crashes as the user still did not reply.

Comment: Which is why only execute code when your app starts if you have permissions and, if you don't, you wait until you receive the `PERMISSION_GRANTED` callback. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to block, either with `Thread#sleep` or with while loops, as the permission request is asynchronous. Here's how your Activity should flow:

First, define the logic that requires permissions in order to run:

```
private void onPermissionGranted() {
   //code to execute
}
```

Then, in `onCreate()`, check to see whether you have those permissions. If you do, execute your code. If you don't, request the permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,/*permissions*/) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    onPermissionGranted();
} else {
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, /*permissions*/, /*request_code*/); 
}
```

When the permission status has updated, it calls through to `onRequestPermissionsResult`. If the permission was granted, then act on it here. Otherwise, do something else (either reshow the dialog or finish the activity).

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case /*our request code from before*/: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                onPermissionGranted();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions are required in order to run this app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For android to get permissions you need to go in the android manifest and then add your permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Like this

Answer (score 1):

According to [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for requesting the permission first check if permission is granted or not:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is not granted
}
```

and if not granted request for it:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
```

and finally for handling the result of the request use this code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted, yay!
            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the android manifest and add

This works with xamarin and unity

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use some library. As an example you can use [TedPersmission](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission). It is really easy to use.

If you want to implement the logic yourself and not use any libraries, then you should ask for a permission, have a listener (`onRequestPermissionsResult`) for when the permission has been granted/denied, if it was denied then inform the user and don't let him continue. If it was granted then ask for a second permission and have a second listener to see if the user granted this permission and so on until the user has granted/denied every permission you need.